# How to get an array of character (A-z, no numbers) from a given string?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I need a java regex to answer my question.

this is my code:

```
char[] array = s.split("regex");
```

Comment: Why do you need a regex? And `split()` doesn't return `char[]` anyway.

Comment: "this is my code". Considering the code, I understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add a sample input and the expected output?

Comment: yeah my mistake, but i mean if i have this String: 123abc345def, how do i spilit it to an array of character: a[0]=a, a[1]=b, .....

Answer (score 0):

First replace non-letter characters with blank space, then convert String to char array:

```
char[] onlyLetters = "regex".replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", "").toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comment below your question, what you really want, is to get the individual characters of that given string, which can be achieved by the `toCharArray()` method in the `String` class.

```java
String s = "ABCDEfghi1234";
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
```

If you also need to limit the resulting chars to a defined set of characters, you have to remove all others from the string first, which can be done with a simple regex-replace.

```java
String s = "ABCDEfghi1234_.,-DSsf";
s = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
```

The `split` method you used is normally used to split strings at defined positions, e.g. if you want to split a sentence, separated by spaces.

```java
String sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
String[] words = sentence.split("\\s");
// words now contains the extracted words of the sentence
// words[0] == "The"
// words[1] == "quick"
// ...
```